# Webpack implicit vendor/manifest chunks in IE11 - Promise is undefined

Tags: webpack, babel-polyfill, commonschunkplugin

**Short version**

When I run my application in IE11, I get an error saying **`Promise is undefined`** from within the manifest.js file.

*How do I add `babel-polyfill` or similar such that it runs **before** the manifest is executed?*

**Long version**

I am trying to add CommonsChunkPlugin to my webpack config in order to split off third party (npm package) scripts into a separate bundle. As per the Webpack 2 documentation I have set up "[combined implicit common vendor chunks and manifest file](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#combining-implicit-common-vendor-chunks-and-manifest-file)" which is working well in modern browsers.

I have written a function to ensure that the chunks get included into my index file in the right order (see below).

A bit of background on my two explicit entry points:

- legacy_libs - Older libraries that are placed into the global namespace with `script-loader`. I hope to phase these out over time
- main - My main app entry point

The other two (vendor and manifest) are implicit and created with CommonsChunkPlugin.

When I run this with IE11, I get an error: **`Promise is undefined`**. This seems to be because the webpack manifest itself is calling `new Promise()`.

In my main entry point I have `import 'babel-polyfill';`. Before I added the vendor & manifest chunking, this allowed me to overcome IE's lack of Promises. But now that I have manifest.js loading first, I can't work out how to include it in the right order.

My config looks like so:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    legacy_libs: './app/libs.js',
    main: './app/main.js'
  },
  ...
  plugins: [
    // Extract third party libraries into a separate vendor bundle.
    // Also extract webpack manifest into its own bundle (to prevent vendor hash changing when app source changes)
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: function (module) {
        return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest'
    }),

    // Generate index.html file.
    // Include script bundles in the right order based on chunk name prefixes.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.ejs',
      chunksSortMode: function (a, b) {
        const chunkOrder = ['manifest', 'vendor', 'legacy_libs', 'main'];
        const aChunk = chunkOrder.findIndex(chunk => a.names[0].startsWith(chunk));
        const bChunk = chunkOrder.findIndex(chunk => b.names[0].startsWith(chunk));
        const aValue = (aChunk > -1) ? aChunk : chunkOrder.length;
        const bValue = (bChunk > -1) ? bChunk : chunkOrder.length;
        return aValue - bValue;
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue introduced with webpack 2.6.0, a bug is already issued: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4916

So either wait until the bugfix gets released or revert back to 2.5.1!

Comment: Thank you so much @Sheeni! As you say, reverting to Webpack 2.5.1 fixes the issue and also thank you for linking to the issue on Github. I will keep an eye out for a bugfix.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. My config is similar to yours (vendor & manifest). The way I solved it was to add `babel-polyfill` in the entry point of my manifest. Your `entry` should look like this:

```
entry: {
    legacy_libs: './app/libs.js',
    main: './app/main.js',
    manifest: 'babel-polyfill'
}
```

This will load the polyfill so it can be used in the manifest file.

**EDIT:** Using this returned another error when building (although it  runs fine on the dev-server):

> ERROR in CommonsChunkPlugin: While running in normal mode it's not allowed to use a non-entry chunk (manifest)

Fixed it by modifying the entry points and the CommonsChunkPlugin so it looks like this:

```
entry: {
    legacy_libs: './app/libs.js',
    main: './app/main.js',
    'babel-polyfill': 'babel-polyfill'
},
...
plugins: [
    ...
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'manifest',
        chunks: 'babel-polyfill'
    }),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Fleezey - this still doesn't seem to work for me though. It causes it to create a babel-polyfill.js file (starting with `webpackJsonp([3]....`. If I include that file before manifest.js then I get an error about `webpackJsonp` not existing, and if I include it after the manifest then I get my original problem of the manifest using Promise which is not polyfilled.